# How to share configuration object across Lamdas?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, configuration, aws-lambda, aws-config

I need an application configuration parameter (probably a JSON object) shared across 2 Lamdas. Parameter is changed by CloudWatch event and, reflecting an auto-scaling group size.

AWS Config looks like an overkill to me. DynamoDB/S3 may be a solution, but still looks a lot of overhead to me. Is there a better/simpler solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you want to achieve, but if you simply want to share one param with multiple functions, AWS SSM Parameter Store is an option. If param is confidential, then Secrets Manager might be in order.

But since you mention that param is going to be changed by Cloudwatch event somehow, maybe feeding event into [SNS-SQS fanout scheme](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/send-fanout-event-notifications/) is what you're looking for.